# How do you plot a line with constant length and a random Angle in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a single line with a **constant length**. I have written the below code but the lines seems to keep changing length. How do I fix this?

```
clear
clc

Length = 5;
N = 1;

X1 = rand(1,N) + Length;
Y1 = rand(1,N) + Length;
Angle = rand(1,N)*360; % angles to be in degrees
X2 = Length*cos(Angle) + X1;
Y2 = Length*cos(Angle) + Y1;

AxisValues = axes;
plot(AxisValues, [X1 Y1], [X2 Y2])
```

And this is what I get.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What is `L`? Why is `Lenght` never used? Is this the actual code?

Comment: @AnderBiguri that was i typo! L is length. Corrected!

Comment: But also `Clear` is capitalized. My point: this is not the code you are working with, it does not run. Show us something you at least tried to use.

Comment: @AnderBiguri it run well on my side, the `Clear` is clearly another typo which has now been corrected.

Comment: Yeah, which worried me, because when you share working code you copy paste, so typos are impossible! Thanks for updating the code.

Comment: `cosd` <- degrees, `cos()`<-radians. Also, maybe you need `sin` in some place? check the maths ;) With 2 cos, if `cos(theta)==0`, then your new point is the same as the old!

Comment: @AnderBiguri because i have random coordinates for the starting points and end points. I am trying to figure out the maths for a fixed Length

Comment: Your answer does not follow any logic related to my comment. Learn some trigonometry! The wikipedia page should be enough to fix the issue. I insist, there is a `sin` missing. I am not being very specific with my answer because this looks like a textbook homework question and I just hint to solution, not give solutions, to those.

Answer (score 1):

the following code does what you asked for

```
clear all;close all;clc

L0 = 5;
N = 10;

A1 = rand(1,N)*360 % random angles

% generate 1st point

X0=rand(1,1)
Y0=rand(1,1)

X1=X0;
Y1=Y0;

for k=2:1:N-1
    xn=X1(k-1)+L0*cosd(A1(k));
    yn=Y1(k-1)+L0*sind(A1(k));
    X1=[X1 xn];
    Y1=[Y1 yn];
end

figure;
ax=gca
plot(ax,X1,Y1)
ax.DataAspectRatio=[1 1 1];
grid on
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');
```

sample output

[image]

Comment: `clear all` is bad practice. `clear` by itself clears all variables from the workspace. `clear all` also clears function definitions and other things that usually don’t need clearing, and will only slow you down. See the docs.

Comment: @JohnBofarull Thanks but the line is meant to be only "one line with a fixed length" generated with a random angle to the horizontal axis within the plot area

Comment: To Fil: then set N=1 and you get the single segment with the random angle. If you use radians, then you can use sin() cos() tand() functions. But if you intend to use degree values, then use sind() cosd() and tand() functions instead.

Comment: To Cris: <clear all> removes all variables, to avoid variables overlapping. Clearing the workspace is a way to avoid problems. Obviously if you want to save time, you can avoid clear all with selective clearing, but usually workspaces of question originators are unknown to those attempting to supply answers, it is safe to say that a starting line like [tag:clear all;close all;clc] is a good practice to avoid problems: It's a common practice in Mathworks forum.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to understand your code meaning, but
I suggest you can adjust your plot with `xlim` `ylim` to grab the range.

and one more tip is you have to use the trigonometric (e.g., cos) with radian argument. If you want to use it as a degree you can use `cosd`

Comment: `xlim` and `ylim` doesn't work for a line plot of fixed length. I want the `xlim` and `ylim` to determined by `xlim([-20 20])`. Its the trigonometry which I think is the problem.